# Reactour and focus issues on re-render

Tags: reactjs, input, tabindex

### The Scenario

I am using the [Reactour](https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour) library to create a guided tutorial on my website. The library allows me to interact with highlighted components, which is the desired behavior. However, my input boxes have a `onBlur` attribute that updates the state in a parent component, thus re-rendering the child (component where the input boxes are).

### The Issue

The problem is that this re-render is messing up the `focus` and the user is not able to "tab" between fields (when the tutorial is open). It seems that the Reactour component is receiving the focus after the re-render, even though they have a `tabIndex="-1"` set by default in their component.

### My Approach

I tried to set explicit `tabIndex` properties, but that didn't work.

I thought about having an `onKeyDown` listener, check if the pressed key is <kbd>tab</kbd> and "manually" control the `focus` between fields, but that seems too hacky and messy, considering I have a lot of fields in my form.

---

I made a CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-golick-wpy3r) to reproduce the bug. You will notice that you can tab between inputs when the Tutorial is closed, but clicking the "Start Tour" button will mess the `tabIndex` behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, this seems to be an issue with Reactour and it was logged [here](https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour/issues/185). Hopefully, it will be fixed soon.

For now, as a workaround, my solution was to manually set the `tabIndex` of Reactour components during initialization:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#___reactour button");
    elements.forEach((el) => (el.tabIndex = -1));
}, 100);
```

The `timeout` is necessary since it takes a little bit for the elements to show up in the screen.